# Get Cognito auth events for display in the UI?

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In Amazon Cognito, when selecting a user, I can see the auth events below, e.g.

[image]

My question is, **how may I retrieve these auth events for displaying in the UI?**

So far I have been using the Auth library in AWS Amplify to sign in and sign out, as part of an Angular app. I cannot see anything on the Auth class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

On the client you can use Hub

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/hub/q/platform/js#authentication-events

```
import { Hub, Logger } from 'aws-amplify';

const logger = new Logger('My-Logger');

const listener = (data) => {

    switch (data.payload.event) {

        case 'signIn':
            logger.error('user signed in'); //[ERROR] My-Logger - user signed in
            break;
        case 'signUp':
            logger.error('user signed up');
            break;
        case 'signOut':
            logger.error('user signed out');
            break;
        case 'signIn_failure':
            logger.error('user sign in failed');
            break;
        case 'configured':
            logger.error('the Auth module is configured');

    }
}

Hub.listen('auth', listener);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think this will set up a listener for new events, not allow me to retrieve historic events, is that correct?

Comment: I think you will probably have to reach out to some aws-sdk apis to get this feature going